# Distance between allocated variables on the buffer

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory

I am reading this book, and it shows a demo of heap-based overflow.

However, I do not understand why the distance between two variables on the heap is 104 bytes instead of 100.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JOM3.png)

I also typed out the code and ran it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {


  char* buffer;
  char* datafile;
  buffer = (char *) malloc(100); 
    datafile = (char *) malloc(20); 


    printf("Address of buffer:   %p\n", buffer);
    printf("Address of datafile: %p\n", datafile);

printf("Distance: %d\n", (int)datafile- (int)buffer);


}
```

output

```
> clang-7 -pthread -lm -o main main.c
>./main
Address of buffer:   0xf07260
Address of datafile: 0xf072d0
Distance: 112
```

The distance I got from testing the code is 112 instead of 104 which is written in the book.

Why is it not 100 bytes away, but instead it is 104 bytes as stated in the book?
Why is the result completely different from what I expected / from the book when I ran the code on my computer?

Comment: Different implementations of memory allocation routines arrange their memory in different ways, due to alignment considerations and other issues. Also, there is no actual question in your post. When posting a question to Stack Overflow, be sure to ask a specific question.

Comment: Usually there is a header information of the allocated block, just before returned pointer. It is implementation specific and usually size of the "gap" depends on the architecture and pointer size.

Comment: "Why is the result completely different from what I expected..." Because your expectations were wrong. There no way to predict the distance between two malloc'ed memory areas. They can be anywhere.

Comment: Further... a quick look at the picture from the book strongly suggest that you shall get another book... In the small part posted there are both incorrect statements and bad code...

Comment: And this code ... `printf("Distance: %d\n", (int)datafile- (int)buffer);` is illegal C code.

Comment: @4386427 The excerpt is from _Jon Erickson: "Hacking: The Art of Exploitation"_. It seems to be specifically about vulnerabilities, not generally teaching C.

Comment: See section 6.5.6 (https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6) "When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object".  In your case, the two pointers do not point to elements of the same array object, so the subtraction is undefined.

Comment: @user17732522 well, okay... I didn't notice that it was on purpose. I did read all details just took a quick look. That said, having undefine behavior in the code is still bad and unnecessay for the example..

Comment: @4386427 Could you share which are the incorrect statements, and why bad code?

Answer (score 0):

When you are on a x86-32, data on the heap is aligned at 4 bytes for pre-MMX and 8 bytes for post-MMX. There's also a size_t length header to hold the allocation length, so allocating 100 bytes need 4 byte header rounded up to a multiple of 4 (or 8) gives 104 bytes (4×26 or 8×13).

When you are on a x86-64, data on the heap is aligned at 16 bytes (since SSE needs to be aligned), while AVX (1&2) needs 32 bytes alignment, so you will need aligned_alloc() for them instead of having compilers increase the heap spacing. Allocating 100 bytes with an 8 byte header size_t gives 108 bytes, but rounds up to multiple of 16 gives 112 bytes (16×7).

The length header is usually hashed, so that users should not peek at them easily. Extensions exist such as _msize() for Visual C.

Edit: the x86-32 also expands to 16 byte alignment for SSE.